# whitespace-mode ignores whitespace-line-column

Tags: whitespace, buffer-local, whitespace-mode

In `~/.emacs` I've globally enabled `whitespace-mode`:

```
(require 'whitespace)
(setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))
(global-whitespace-mode t)
```

Example buffer content:

```
-*- fill-column: 100; whitespace-line-column: nil -*-
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

According to documentation for `whitespace-line-column`: *If nil, the `fill-column' variable value is used.* However, that doesn't happen. In the buffer with the above sample content, highlight starts at column 80 (default value):

[image: Screenshot with highlight starting at column 80]

What I already tried, to no avail:

- Enabled `whitespace-mode` for that buffer explicitly.
- Buffer local: `whitespace-line-column: 100`
- In `~/.emacs`: `whitespace-line-column: nil`, `whitespace-line-column: 100`

Version: `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (i686-pc-mingw32) of 2014-10-24 on LEG570`

*How can I specify line length for `whitespace-mode` for an individual buffer?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First off, since you didn't mention it: Using the same version of Emacs (24.4.1), the behavior you describe can be reproduced in `emacs -Q`.

Secondly, what you are doing *should* work (AFAICT). It seems that turning on `whitespace-mode` globally (or even in a mode hook) *before* visiting a file with a custom `whitespace-line-column` is what's causing the problem. You might want to consider reporting the issue to the Emacs devs via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `report-emacs-bug`.

Finally, you can get the behavior you want by doing the following:

1. Change your config to

   ```el
   (require 'whitespace)
   (setq whitespace-style '(face empty tabs lines-tail trailing))
   (add-hook 'hack-local-variables-hook 'whitespace-mode)
   ```
2. Change headers of any files that should use a custom `whitespace-line-column` to

   ```
   -*- whitespace-line-column: 100; -*-
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! However, manually enabling `whitespace-mode` every time I open a new file is really not an option for me.

Comment: @feklee OK, it turns out there is a hook called `hack-local-variables-hook` that gets run after applying [file-local variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Local-Variables.html). If you add `whitespace-mode` to this hook, it will behave correctly for files that use a custom `whitespace-line-column` (and you won't have to turn it on manually). I updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Works great so far! Starting `whitespace-mode` from `hack-local-variables-hook` makes it also respect a global setting of `whitespace-line-column: nil`. So I don't need to specify an explicit value in every file.

Comment: this isn't working for me, the whitespace-line-column keeps reverting to the default.

Comment: aha! I had `:safe` local variables set, and this needs to be added to the safe list.

Comment: FYI `(put 'whitespace-line-column 'safe-local-variable #'integerp)` lets me use these settings as safe variables.

Comment: was this ever reported as a bug upstream? `auto-insert-alist` templates are able to see local variables, so I presume `auto-insert-mode` is doing The Right Thing.

Comment: I have also run into the same problem and have reported the bug here: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=24904